# Conky black background on Unity

Tags: unity, conky

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 (and 14.04 on another computer) with Unity. Conky doesn't work like I expect. This is my config:

```
alignment top_right
background yes
border_inner_margin 0
border_width 0
top_cpu_separate yes
default_color ffffff
default_outline_color 000000
#default_shade_color 999999
double_buffer yes
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders yes
draw_outline yes
draw_shades no
gap_x 0
gap_y 30
maximum_width 222
minimum_size 222
own_window yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_type override
own_window_class conky-semi
show_graph_scale yes
total_run_times 0
update_interval 5
text_buffer_size 1024
use_xft yes
xftfont Ubuntu:size=8
```

In this config Conky have black background, not disappear when showing or clicking desktop. If I change own_window_type to 'desktop' Conky runs with transparency but if I click on desktop it disappear (but still working). If I change own_window_type to 'normal' it have transparency and doesn't disappear on clicking on desktop but it minimize when I click on show desktop button and doesn't recover (still running).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If I change own_window_type to 'normal' it have transparency and doesn't disappear on clicking on desktop but it minimize when I click on show desktop button and doesn't recover (still running)."

**Do not minimize on Show Desktop**

**Using Compiz:** If the 'Show Desktop' button or key-binding minimizes Conky along with all other windows, start the Compiz configuration settings manager, go to "General Options" and uncheck the "Hide Skip Taskbar Windows" option.

[image]

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky

Comment: YES!! IT WORKS :D

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, I found a setting that gets it "almost" right, try it yourself, see if it helps

```
own_window_class Conky
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_argb_visual yes 
own_window_argb_value 25
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
```

Comment: Setting `own_window_type` to normal breaks it as explained in the OP.

Comment: Conky minimize when hit "show desktop"

Comment: For me, all I needed from your answer was the two lines `own_window_argb_visual yes` and 
`own_window_argb_value 25`. This removed the black BG

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this lines:

```
own_window_type normal

own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
```

Comment: The OP has already tried this: " If I change own_window_type to 'normal' [...]  it minimize when I click on show desktop button and doesn't recover", the `own_window_hints` are exactly the same as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this properly that works on Unity (it will on other desktop environments). However, here a workaround: use `xdotool` to make `conky` visible again after you loose it:

1. Install `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Use these settings in your `~/.conkyrc`:

   ```
   own_window yes
   own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
   own_window_transparent yes
   own_window_argb_visual yes
   own_window_argb_value 0
   own_window_type desktop
   own_window_class conky
   ```
3. Now, when you loose `conky`, you can get it back by running this command:

   ```
   xdotool windowactivate `xdotool search  --class conky`
   ```
4. Create this little script and save it as `run_conky.sh`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   ## Kill any existing conoky instance
   killall conky

   ## Launch conky
   conky &

   ## As long as conky is running, run the xdotool command
   ## to make it visible every two seconds
   while true; do
       pgrep conky && xdotool windowactivate `xdotool search  --class conky`
       sleep 2
   done
   ```
5. Make the script executable (`chmod +x start_conky.sh`) and add it to your startup applications. Basically, use the script to launch `conky` at login instead of running the `conky` command.

The result of this is that `conky` will magically appear after 2 seconds (change the `sleep` value to 1 to make it faster but 2 is fine and is less of a load on your system). I tested it on Unity on 13.10 and it works fine.

Comment: No change. When own_window_type is set to desktop Conky disappear when click on desktop.

Comment: @QkiZ did you also remove the `own_window_class` or at least set it to `conky`?

Comment: Yes. In both cases, the same effect.

Comment: @QkiZ you're right, sorry, on my machine it only disappears if I click on the desktop _after_ clicking on "show desktop" so I didn't notice at first.

Comment: @QkiZ see updated answer, I found a workaround.

Comment: This workaround works but this is not solution. But @xangua found solution (below) :) Thanx anyway